# Capturar datas de um texto usando expressão regular em javascript

Tags: javascript, string, regex, data

Eu tenho uma função que retorna dados em JSON e coloca em determinados lugares com jQuery.
Um desses dados é um texto que contem um período de datas (Inicio e fim).

**Exemplo do texto retornado:**

*ESPÍRITO SANTO - Estado: Isto é quanto o brasileiro já pagou de tributos no período de 01/01/2014 até 11/03/2014*

No caso acima eu quero retornar somente essas duas datas, 01/01/2014 e 11/03/2014.

Já ví vários exemplos em javascript de capturar textos entre caracteres definidos, mas não de capturar um formato de texto (no caso uma data) e retornar só aquilo ali.

Então tem como eu retornar somente essas duas datas? Que função eu devo usar?

Comment: O formato é sempre `dd/mm/aaaa`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use expressões regulares.

```
var datas = texto.match(/\b(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\b/g);
console.log(datas); // output: [ "01/01/2014", "11/03/2014" ]
```

Nesse caso em especial você pega todas as strings que contêm três sequências numéricas separadas por uma barra (`/`).

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado..

Answer (score 2):

Uma expressão regular para recuperar datas no formado `dd/mm/aaaa` é `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}`.

Em javascript, você pode criar a expressão regular e então usar a função `exec` para iterar sobre os itens encontrados;

Exemplo:

```js
var pat = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/g;
var resultados = [];
var item;
while (item = pat.exec(str)) {
    resultados.push(item[0]);
}
```

As ocorrências estariam no array `resultados`.

E encapsulando tudo numa função podemos fazer assim:

```
function getDatas(str) {
    var pat = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/g;
    var resultados = [];
    var item;
    while (item = pat.exec(str)) {
        resultados.push(item[0]);
    }
    return resultados
}
```

### [Veja o exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/ZZsy7/)

(não esqueça de abrir o console do seu navegador para ver a saída)

Answer (score 1):

```
var reg = /([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4})/g;
var str = "Um texto com uma data aqui 01/01/2012 e mais uma aqui 03/04/2000";
var todasAsDatas = str.match(reg);
```

É importante lembrar que o `g` no final da expressão regular especifica que devem ser retornadas todas as ocorrências.

Essa expressão permite datas como 1/9/2013, ou 01/09/2013.

Answer (score 0):

Se o formato for sempre `dd/mm/aaaa`, a expressão regular é muito simples:

```
\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}
```

<sup>[Teste online](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C%2F%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C%2F%5Cd%7B4%7D&input=ESP%C3%8DRITO%20SANTO%20-%20Estado%3A%20Isto%20%C3%A9%20quanto%20o%20brasileiro%20j%C3%A1%20pagou%20de%20tributos%20no%20per%C3%ADodo%20de%2001%2F01%2F2014%20at%C3%A9%2011%2F03%2F2014)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Acho importante limitar um pouco as expressões erradas possíveis. Na expressão abaixo só não restrinjo as diferenças de dias por mês e o ano bissexto, nem limito um ano mínimo de início.

```
var reg = /(([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}|3[0-1]{1})\/(0[0-9]{1}|1[0-2]{1})\/[0-9]{4})/g;
var str = "Um texto com uma data aqui 01/01/2012 mas essa data errada aqui não pegaria 32/13/2000";
var todasAsDatas = str.match(reg);
```

Comment: Segue uma versão mais completa, troto numero de dias dos meses.... so fevereiro que ficou com 29 dias sempre.... Ano também só aceita de 1960 pra cima.

((((0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(01|03|05|07|08|10|12))|((0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)\/(04|06|09|11))|((0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])\/(02)))\/(19[6-9][0-9]|2[0-9]{3}))